# hibernate doesn't create tables postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I know that there is a lot of similar questions here, but I've spent all day and didn't find a solution.

I'm using Hibernate 5.0.12 with PostgreSQL 9.6.3 in Spring Boot 1.5.4 project.

I have a simple user entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String email;
    private String password;

    public Long getId() {       return id;  }
    public void setId(Long id)  {       this.id = id;   }
    public String getEmail() {      return email;   }
    public void setEmail(String email) {        this.email = email; }
    public String getPassword() {       return password;    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {      this.password = password; }
}
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my-db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG
```

Launching looks normal

[hibernate logs](https://gist.github.com/kimreik/f59235dee6a0efa17f004ed3d70623a9)

but table "user" hasn't been created.

With MySQL all works fine. Is there any issue with PostgreSQL? I'm new in it and just created DB like that:

```
createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres my-db password *********
```

and, after some tries to fix the issue, created schema in it:

```
CREATE SCHEMA "my-db" AUTHORIZATION postgres;
```

Comment: DB from logs is `company-crm` `url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/company-crm`. Are you looking at the right DB?

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF I've just replaced my company name to "company" in hibernate logs. There is '*company*-crm' instead of 'my-db' in configs. It's the single base on my PC and connect works fine. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL. Use different table name, like `users` and put `@Table(name = "users")` annotation on top of your entity class.

Comment: I've changed table name.
With "user" i got `column user0_.id does not exist` when tried to read from DB.
Now I'm getting  `relation "users" does not exist`.
So, this was part of the problem, but the table is still not being created.

Comment: I would drop all the tables and see again, and in general for local usage `create-drop` seems to be better idea, but can't tell you for sure. I can only suggest to write create table statements by yourself and use Flyway to execute them.

Comment: There is nothing to drop in my case, it's the first try to use postgreSQL in a new project. I think, there is something wrong with my environment. Thanks for Flyway, we'll use something like this.

Answer (score -1):

As per your above code looks like you are missing @Table( name = "user" ) annotation.Can you please try once after adding this if that works?

Comment: May I know please why it is marked as negative vote? by which I can correct myself in future while giving answers of any question.

Comment: Hibernate creates table even without `@Table` annotation, This couldn't be the solution. Even if it is `@Table( name = "user" )` doesn't work as `user` is reserved keyword in Postgre